# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

My application is working with `weblogic10.0` but in `weblogic 12C` it is showing following exception :

```
Servlet failed with an Exception
       java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at javax.faces.context.ExternalContext.getRequestCharacterEncoding(ExternalContext.java:945)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandler.initView(ViewHandler.java:477)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:115)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.PageServer$1.respond(PageServer.java:25)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

can any one help me how to resolve it.

Comment: WebLogic 12c, by default, supports JSF 2.x and JSTL 1.2. If you are using JSF 1.2, you will have to follow these steps to deploy older version of JSF to WebLogic 12c. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/configurejsfandjtsl.htm#autoId3